# How to parse a flat file?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, flat-file

In an Azure Logic App, how can I parse a fixed-position flat file?
The file arrives via FTP. It's a fixed-position ASCII file. E.G. Field 1 is always column 1 through 18. Field 2 is always column 19 through 55. etc. 
My Logic App begins with the FTP When A File Is Added Or Modified connector. Then I do a Get File Content connector.

Next, I envision iterating through each record (new line delimited) and mapping fields to some new data structure.

Is there an easy way to do this? Should I write an Azure Function App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Integration Account** and **Flat File Schemas**, decode/parse the incoming flat file message with the **Flat File Decode** component and mapping to a new data structure with a **Integration Account Map** and the **Transform XML** component.

Comment: Thx. Any guidance on where to find example schema files or documentation. I.E. I need to create a schema for data that looks like this:

Comment: field1.................Field2....................................Field3....Field4...........
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Flat file schemas are the same as in BizTalk Server, you can use any of the BizTalk Server Flat File Schemas sample on internet, for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/walkthrough-creating-a-flat-file-schema-from-a-document-instance

Comment: I can't find any sample *output* examples of the Flat File Wizard, nor can I find any place to download the wizard/tooling for Visual Studio. I do not have BizTalk nor do I plan to get it.

Comment: You can download de BizTalk Developer edition and install only the Visual Studio tools. Here you have a complete walkthrough https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/walkthrough-creating-a-flat-file-schema-from-a-document-instance